# Host code at Different location in apache2 linux

Tags: apache-2.2

I need host my project in linux (ubuntu) server. By default I will put the code in /var/www/. How do I create a custom directory structure and put my code over there or else suggest some way that I could run my code in a secure way in apache.

I need step by step procedure could anyone please help and guide me through this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step procedures are normally outside the scope of SF answers.

By default `/var/www` is the `DocumentRoot` of the default vhost in Ubuntu.

To make a custom directory structure [mkdir](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) would the normal choice if you have access to a shell. If not you will need to set up an ftp server and configure an account with the correct permissions to access `/var/www` through the ftp server. You can then use an ftp client like filezilla to create yout directory structure and upload files etc.